# how to switch between two form for website visitor once admin logged in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am facing problem: I have two forms form1 and form2 now. What I want to achive is once the admin logged in anywhere all the visitor (non logged in) to my wordpress site should see form1 on page.

Else, they should see form2? What I did is below:

```
if(current_user_can('author' )|| current_user_can('administrator')) 
    {    
          show form1    
       }
else {   
           show form2
    }
```

Now, this works fine but only for admin screen not other user or visitor. I want this to be universal.

Thanks in advance. I am using this code in custom page template. Please help me, guys. Any tutorial will also help me or if there is any other way to achieve this. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will have to register the admins logging in or out somewhere. To do so I would use a transient to keep an eye on whos logging in, and registering it if its an admin (someone capable of managing the settings).

The following is not tested, but should work. Past all of this into `functions.php`, or create a plugin from it:

```
//This function checks anyone logging in, and adds it to the database if its an admin.

add_action('wp', 'update_online_users_status'); //Registeres the function

function update_online_users_status(){
    $lastActive = 5 * 60; //An admin vas last active 5 mins ago (5 x 60 secs)

    if(is_user_logged_in()){
            // get the online users list, if theres anyone already logged in
                if(($logged_in_users = get_transient('admins_online')) === false)    $logged_in_users = array();
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                    $current_user = $current_user->ID;  
                    $current_time = current_time('timestamp');

                    if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) { //Checks if its an admin logging in
                            if(!isset($logged_in_users || ($logged_in_users < ($current_time - ($lastActive)))){
                                $logged_in_users = $current_time;
                                set_transient(‘admins_online', $logged_in_users, $lastActive);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}

//The actual check. Returns true/false based on if theres been an active admin for the past x minutes
function is_there_an_admin_online() {

  // get the online users list
  $logged_in_users = get_transient('admins_online');

  return isset($logged_in_users && ($logged_in_users > (current_time('timestamp') - (5 * 60)));
}
```

Set whatever timeout you want, by replacing `5 * 60` - one time in each of the above functions.

Then you will be able to do a check like so:

```
$isAdminOnline = is_there_an_admin_online();
if( $isAdminOnline == true ) 
    {    
          show form1    
       }
else {   
           show form2
    }
```